# c++ adding two wchar_t vars

Tags: c++, visual-c++

windows platform.
szPath is pre defined. i want to add szPath2 to it but i don't want to use the [PathAppend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function because i 'll need to link the Shlwapi library.

what should i do? i want to return a wchat_t..

```
wchar_t szPath[MAX_PATH];
wchar_t szPath2[MAX_PATH] = L"\\project\\MyApplication.exe";
```

Comment: Those are not `wchar_t` s; they are **arrays of** `wchar_t`. By "add" I assume you mean you want to concatenate the strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any reason you aren't using `std::wstring`?

You can also use [`wcsncat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms860445.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard wide-char concatenation function, `wcscat` or any of its friends as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wcscat`. The signature of the function is as follws. If you know `strcat`, it's the same function but works with `whcar_t` instead.

`wchar_t *wcscat (wchar_t *dest, const wchar_t *src);`

It will put `src` at the end of `dest` and handle the null terminating character as well. Of course, `dest` should have sufficient **space** available, and the two arrays shouldn't overlap.

See [MSDN article on string concatenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1x0y282%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for further details.